# How to make function with multiple parameters with different data type in pascal?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have made a function with 2 parameters with the same data type and I have no problem with that.

But I'm having trouble with different data type

Here's my code  :

```
uses crt;
function inputscore(name : string, score:integer) : integer;

begin
     writeln('My name is ',name,' and my score is ',score);
     inputscore:=0;
end;

begin
    clrscr;

    inputscore('David',98);
    readkey;
end.
```

But It returned this error message:

`multipleparameterfunc.pas(2,34)Fatal syntax error, ")" expected but "," found`

Comment: A comma is used if you have more than one parameter tagged with the same type: `a, b: string` versus `a: string; b: string` or `a: string: b: integer`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Pascal you separate the arguments with a `;`.
So your definition has to look like this:

```
function inputscore(name: string; score: integer) : integer;
```

When you call the function then you still use a `,` to separate the parameters:

```
inputscore('David', 98);
```